# Entity Framework database initialization - for fixed lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use EF v6.1.3 on an ASP.net MVC project in C#.

I have some table I'm willing to initialize by code. Those tables contains fixed values that will populate dropdowns in the app and options are not supposed to be changed.

Is there an elegant way to do it in EF configuration or do I create a startup script that checks whether the lines are already in DB ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. What have you tried? Did you find out about migrations and the Seed() method?

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3 will get you started with code first migrations and seeding your db

Comment: Hi and thanks. I currently have a class in my App_start folder to simply create the db objects. Seeding seemed more for testing than for actual initialization data (initialization as needed for production)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works perfectly that way:

Create a class in App_Start called DatabaseConfig

Create a static method that

1. Checks if the item is already in DB/table
2. Creates it if not

Call the static method from Global.asax

Thanks.